# Can anyone help me convert this MSSQL query to ORACLE?

Tags: oracle

This is my MSSQL query

```
UPDATE  YT 
  SET     POSITION = RN 
                  FROM    ( 
                   SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PARENTID ORDER BY ID) - 1 RN 
                  FROM  CONVERTED 
                   ) YT
```

and this is my attempt at converting it to Oracle

```
UPDATE  CONVERTED 
  SET     POSITION = (SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PARENTID ORDER BY ID) - 1 RN 
                  FROM  CONVERTED 
                   );
```

Ufortunately I get this error

```
SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `id` is unique, the following should work in both databases:

```
UPDATE  CONVERTED 
    SET POSITION = (select count(*) - 1
                    from converted c2
                    where c2.parentid = converted.parentid and
                          c2.id <= converted.id
                   );
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for something like this ?

```
SQL> create table t (id int, parentid int, position int)
```

2  /

```
SQL> begin
  2  insert into t values(1,null,null);
  3  insert into t values(10,null,null);
  4  insert into t values(3,1,null);
  5  insert into t values(7,1,null);
  6  insert into t values(4,1,null);
  7  insert into t values(19,7,null);
  8  insert into t values(11,7,null);
  9  insert into t values(72,10,null);
 10  insert into t values(42,10,null);
 11  insert into t values(23,10,null);
 12  commit;
 13  end;
 14  /

SQL> merge into t using
  2  (select id, row_number() over (partition by parentid order by id) - 1 rn
  3  from  t) src
  4  on (src.id = t.id)
  5  when matched then
  6    update set t.position = src.rn
  7  /

SQL> select * from t
  2  start with parentid is null
  3  connect by prior id = parentid
  4  order siblings by position
  5  /

        ID   PARENTID   POSITION                                                
---------- ---------- ----------                                                
         1                     0                                                
         3          1          0                                                
         4          1          1                                                
         7          1          2                                                
        11          7          0                                                
        19          7          1                                                
        10                     1                                                
        23         10          0                                                
        42         10          1                                                
        72         10          2
```